# Multiple values in nested elastic search 2 query

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a nested object named 'bundles', that usually contains more than one object. Using this query I can succesfully query on the id of an object in bundles, but I fail to write a query that can query on multiple id's. Suggestions?

```html
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "bundles",
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "match": {
                "bundles.id": 43273
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "inner_hits": {}
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you want "should" instead of "must" in the boolean filter. For example:

```
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "bundles",
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "should": [
            {
              "match": {
                "bundles.id": 43273
              },
              {
              "match": {
                "bundles.id": 433373
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You could also use terms query if the field can be matched exactly. For example:

```
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "bundles",
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "terms": {
                "bundles.id": [1140000000, 114]
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'
```